# Getting Excel to use displayed decimal places in calculations

Tags: excel

I am using excel to make a spreadsheet with a lot of calculations and a lot of them are off because of one minor issue. If I have cell A1 with a calculation such as `=5.75*1.02`, it will display just fine as `5.87`. My problem is that I then have another cell referring to it as `=A1*1050000` but it returns `6,158,250` which is `5.865*1050000` rather than returning the result of `5.87*1050000`. Is there a setting that will make it so that it calculates based on the displayed decimal places rather than the other number?

I hope this makes sense.

I am using Excel:Mac 2011.

Comment: Not a programming question. Better suited to Super User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll look into whether there is a setting to use displayed text instead of actual values. I doubt there is one though. Here's a reference that talks about [Cell Values and Displayed Text](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/values.htm).

However, if you want to only use to the 2nd decimal digit, just round A1 when you want to use it. (Or Round A1 in it's cell)

I.E.

```
=ROUND(A1,2)*1050000
```

Or A1's formula = `=ROUND(5.75*1.02,2)`

Comment: I think rounding may be the solution in that case. I just thought of that right before you suggested it. That works. Thanks!